# Using a Blob as iframe source and a trouble with loading img src images located in a subdirectory

Tags: javascript, html

EDIT: I added live version of the issue here:
https://www.lieksa.info/demot/stackoverflow/blob_issue/problem.html

I am trying to use Javascript to preview images inside an iFrame to show the user how the image looks like. The images are located in a subdirectory, for example: "kuvat/kuva0.jpg".

If a user presses "preview" button, I take the generated html data **(html source data in a string format)** and turn it into a Blob object and use that as a iframe source for preview.

The generated html and images itself does work, if for example copy-pasted in to a new .html file and displayd via there. Images and everything display nicely.

The problem is that the images in the subdirectory and referenced using "src" inside img html-tag are not working after conversion into iFrame source. What happens to the image source paths and references during the Blob and URL.createObjectURL(blob) process?

Generated html source code includes images in the following way

```
<img src="kuvat/kuva0.jpg" alt="slideshow image">
```

Below is the Blob and iframe process:

```
var html_source = document.getElementById("source_container").value;
var blob = new Blob([html_source], {type: "text/html"});
document.getElementById("iframe_container").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

I even tried only to pass only the image tag in to Blob object and also test a File object. But neither of them worked:

```
var blob = new Blob(['<img src="kuvat/kuva0.jpg" alt="slideshow image">'], {type: "text/html"});
var file = new File(['<img src="kuvat/kuva0.jpg" alt="slideshow image">'], "index.html", { type: "text/plain"});

document.getElementById("preview_container").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// or
document.getElementById("preview_container").src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Comment: Can you provide a live example? Did you try passing those src values as absolute image path?

Comment: A live example is in the post mentioned in <img> tag. the source is passed like that in live version. I also tried with only the image tag as source for the blob: new Blob(['<img src="kuvat/kuva0.jpg" alt="slideshow image">'], {type: "text/html"}); And it did not display the image, it only showed the alternative text. So I suspect something happens to the src path during the conversion and it can't reference the images anymore?

Comment: This is not a live example that reproduce your issue. So, again, can you try with an absolute img path? Do you have any errors in your console in the network tab?

Comment: There is a live example : https://codepen.io/enguerranws/pen/gOaNRNX, it works fine with an absolute img path. So I guess your img path are wrong.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the term "live". Works fine with absolute paths, but I can't get it to work with relative paths. The source does work if I a) copy-paste the generated source into own .html file into the same folder as I am currently in and the photos are in sub-directory. b) I open a new tab via Javascript and write the source into the tab using var tab = window.open('about:blank', '_blank'); tab.document.write(html_source); tab.document.close(); In these two cases, the relative path works, but it doesn't work when I try to use blob method in iframe source. I get no errors in console.

Comment: I guess it can be related to the iframe which can't access to the root document, for security purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your iframe's document's [`baseURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) is set to `blob:https://www.lieksa.info/[UUID]`.

So when the browser will try to resolve the relative path of the image, it will use that `baseURI` to resolve it, resulting in an invalid URI:

```js
const http_base = "https://www.lieksa.info/[UUID]";
console.log( 'http:', new URL( "kuva1.jpg", http_base ) ); // Success

const blob_base = "blob:https://www.lieksa.info/[UUID]";
console.log( 'blob:', new URL( "kuva1.jpg", blob_base ) ); // Error
```

To fix that, you can append a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element in the head of your document, **before the `<img>` gets declared**, this will set the correct `baseURI` for your document and the browser will be able to parse your relative path correctly:

```js
const frame = document.getElementById('frame');
const html_content = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test relative URI in blob:// frame</title>
  <!-- here we set the baseURI of our document -->
  <base href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- here we can use relative URIs, as if we were really on wikimedia's page -->
  <img src="PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" width="300">
</body>
</html>`;
const blob = new Blob( [html_content], { type: "text/html" } );
frame.src = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
```

```html
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for : )